Does overriding c.Request.Body with io.NopCloser in a Gin middleware cause potential data leaks?
I'm writing a middleware in Gin to log the request body for debugging purposes. In order to read the body multiple times, I need to use io.NopCloser to reassign c.Request.Body. Here's my current implementation:
return func(c *gin.Context) {
    bodyBytes, _ := io.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
    _ = c.Request.Body.Close()
    
    // Override the Close method of c.Request.Body
    c.Request.Body = io.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(bodyBytes))

    var bodyJSON map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(bodyBytes, &bodyJSON)
    if err != nil {
        c.Next()
        return
    }

    logrus.WithFields(logrus.Fields{
        "method": c.Request.Method + "-request",
        "path":   c.Request.URL.Path,
        "query":  c.Request.URL.RawQuery,
        "body":   bodyJSON,
    }).Info()

    c.Next() 
}

I’m concerned about the use of io.NopCloser, which overrides the Close() method of the request body. Will this cause data leaks since the original Close() method is overidden by an no-op Close() method and does nothing to "close" the request body after I pass it to another middleware?
I’m relatively new to working with IO in Golang, so I’d appreciate any insights or suggestions for a better approach.

By "data leaks", do you mean memory leaks? If yes, then no, what you're doing is safe: the requirement to call Close on the "native" request body is not about memory leaks but about fully consuming the input data from the request—thus being conformant to the protocol and allowing the net/http stack to reuse the underlying TCP socket.

@kostix Yes, I was concern about the memory leaks. So, If I pass this "new" request body to another middleware and do the same thing like I did in this middleware (which is read the body and reassign it), I wouldn't need to call Close right..? Since the Close is now an no-op method and has no effect

As I've said, there's nothing specifically magic in calling the Close method on the body of a request (or the naming of the this method etc). You have to call it on the "real" body to make HTTP protocol work properly and allow net/http to reuse the underlying socket. Once this is done, calling Close is only required because it's part of the API contract. And io.NopCloser exists specifically for cases like this one: when you need to fulfill an API contract while your type does not require "closing" (that is, does not possess any resource other than memory, which is exactly your case).

@kostix I kinda get it... the memory then will be clear out by Garbage Collector right ?

«The memory then will be clear out by Garbage Collector right?»—exactly this! In a program which runs in an environment with automatic GC (such as programs written in Go) you do not generally care about memory deallocation (memory leaks are possible even with automated GC but they should be non-trivial—such as producing and "losing" never-terminating goroutines which hold onto some memory, having memory referenced by global variables etc).

For server requests, you don't need to close the body:

The Server will close the request body. The ServeHTTP
Handler does not need to.

For a client request, you need to close the body due to HTTP implementation particularities. When you need a copy you should use Request.GetBody when available.
Your code is very similar to Gin middleware example code:
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(body))

So I assume it's fine. A “data leak” is mostly a resource leak, since memory leaks are prevented by the garbage collector. What you could leak is unnecessary used resources, like a database connection you don't need any more or a goroutine that does not terminate. There are no such issues here.

Edit: Note that you get the body from the server framework, which it will close by itself. It doesn't say anything about the (possibly replaced) body received by your handler.
Also note that in this case you don't replace a Close function with io.NopCloser, you add one. bytes.NewBuffer gives you a Buffer, which is an io.Reader but has no Close method.

<>--this is the thing I was confusing about. Assuming I remove the Body.Close() in the middleware to make the code identical with your example, then I assign it with NopCloser(), this will override the original Close() method. And finally when the "Server" call Close() on the body, it is not the original Close() anymore. But since the GC takes care of the memory leaks, it makes sense for now.. What frustrates me is that this Body is never actually "closed" if the Close() method has been overridden by NopCloser.
